# How do I INSERT INTO where many fields have their own Select Statements?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a table and i am in the process of inserting rows from another table into it.  However, some of these rows require joins from other tables.  To my knowledge, this means using a subquery select statement in the statement.  the problem is subqueries only return one result, where i may have many.  I am wanting to return a -1 where no records exists.  Here is an example i am using but it is not working:

```
    INSERT INTO [BDW_ReportPrototype].[dbo].[CustomerCreditFact]
    ( [MortgageDimID]
       ,[LeaseDimID]
       ,[OREODimID]
       ,[OfficerTypeDimID] )
    SELECT 
    --[MortgageDimID]
 -2
    --LeaseDimID
,-2
    --OREODimID
,-2
,CASE WHEN OfficerTypeDimID IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE OfficerTypeDimID END 
FROM Staging_FDB_LN_CPDM_Daily LCD  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ERMA..OfficerTypeDim  OTD  on OTD.OfficerNum = LCD.OFFICER 
FROM dbo.Staging_FDB_LN_CPDM_Daily
```

Comment: Please tell us which rdbms you are using and tag the post.

Answer (score 2):

Try this sql statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN OfficerTypeDimID IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE OfficerTypeDimID END
    FROM Staging_FDB_LN_CPDM_Daily LCD 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ERMA..OfficerTypeDim  OTD  on OTD.OfficerNum = LCD.OFFICER
```

Comment: Thank you!  I just gave it a try, and i am receiving a syntex error, but i know it is not your code.  I have several fields i am inserting data into, and you gave me a solution to one of them.  The last peice of syntax,   FROM dbo.Staging_FDB_LN_CPDM_Daily , has an error on the 'FROM, stating i have a syntax error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your complete query?

Comment: Can i email it to you?  Having problems adding it to comments

Comment: I just changed it in my original question to reflect the full table

Comment: New columns are from which table? And also can you post exact error message above. You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create temp workspace for testing and post url that is generated after you run query.

Comment: The new columns are from "dbo.Staging_FDB_LN_CPDM_Daily"

Comment: Are you able to run query without Insert statement?

Answer (score 1):

I would rework your query like the following.

First of all, use a LEFT OUTER JOIN in your query instead of the subqueries. This type of join says a row might exist in the "other" table but it might not but I want a row back regardless.

Now that you know you'll have all your rows, you'll want to see if there is a value there or not. Use the shorthand and easier to maintain check via the coalesce function. It basically is a list of values (column names, variables or hard coded values) and the optimizer will pick the first non-null value from the list and use it. Here we supply -1 for your query

```
INSERT INTO 
    [BDW_ReportPrototype].[dbo].[CustomerCreditFact]
(
    [OfficerTypeDimID]
)
SELECT
    -- coalesce returns the first non-null value
    COALESCE(OTD.OfficerTypeDimID, -1) AS OfficerTypeDimID
FROM 
    dbo.Staging_FDB_LN_CPDM_Daily LCD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ERMA..OfficerTypeDim OTD
        ON OTD.OfficerNum = LCD.OFFICER
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something along these lines...

```
INSERT INTO [BDW_ReportPrototype].[dbo].[CustomerCreditFact]
    ([OfficerTypeDimID])
    Select OfficerTypeDimID 
        from ERMA..OfficerTypeDim  OTD 
        inner JOIN  Staging_FDB_LN_CPDM_Daily LCD 
        on OTD.OfficerNum = LCD.OFFICER
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT -1
   FROM dbo.Staging_FDB_LN_CPDM_Daily LCD
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (
    Select OfficerTypeDimID from ERMA..OfficerTypeDim  
   OTD 
   WHERE
   OTD.OfficerNum = LCD.OFFICER

   )
```